# How to get a typedef struct to work across multiple files files? error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct data'

Tags: c, function, struct, typedef

The struct declaration in my main.c file. I have the function prototype declared but not shown.

```
typedef struct data
{
      int t;
      float tp, tf, tt;
} reactorData;


int main()
{
  reactorData reactorOne[21];

  //other stuff
}
```

This is the function giving me errors in my function.c file. Specifically in the printf() statement.

```
typedef struct data reactorData; //this is what I have up top


void reactorOutput(reactorData  * data)
{
   int c;
   for (c=0;c<21;c++)
   {

    printf(" %3d\t %.0f\t %.0f\t  %.0f\n",c, data[c].tp, data[c].tf, data[c].tt);
   }
}
```

The error reads:
|error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct data'|

The function itself works perfectly fine/ I've tested it within main. Its only when I have it in functions.c it doesn't work.

Comment: @WeatherVane
Those code snippets are from separate files. If I delete that then I get the error that reactorData is an unknown type name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New structs and type definition that must be shared across different compile units are best placed in a header file:

```
// mystructh.h
#ifndef MYSTRUCT_H
#define MYSTRUCT_H

typedef struct data
{
      int t;
      float tp, tf, tt;
} reactorData;

void reactorOutput(reactorData  * data);

// other stuff

#endif
```

then in the other c files you have to include the header

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mystruct.h"

int main(void)
{
  reactorData reactorOne[21];


  // for example
  reactorOutput(reactorOne);

  //other stuff
}
```

**functions.c**

```
// functions.c
#include "mystruct.h"

void reactorOutput(reactorData  * data)
{
   int c;
   for (c=0;c<21;c++)
   {

    printf(" %3d\t %.0f\t %.0f\t  %.0f\n",c, data[c].tp, data[c].tf, data[c].tt);
   }
}
```

The problem with your version is that `struct data` is only defined in `main.c`.
When the compiler compiles `functions.c`, it doesn't know what `struct data` is.
That's why you have to use header files live shown above.

Comment: This solved the issue thank you very much. My professor never mentioned the use of headers to solve this but every related answer I found on stackoverflow concluded the same thing. Is there any way to solve this without using a header?

Comment: @StarchWars no, that's exactly the point of header files. Without header files you would have to declare the same structs and typedef and function prototypes in **every** compile unit. If you later need to change something (add a new member, or remove member), then you would need to change that everywhere. That's the beauty of header files. With header files you would only need to change something in one place and all other compile units that include that header file, see the change as well.